# Cant understand functions parameters

Tags: typescript

Im learing typescript right now, and some friend, who works everyday with typescript, sent me some example code to try to crack it. But it seems like i cant get my head around it ...

The problematic part for me to understand is this:

`{name, surname, age, gender}:iData = {}`, `object = object`, like what ???

```
interface someData{
    name:string;
    surname?:string;
    age:number;
    gender?:"male" | "female";
}

function parseData({name, surname, age, gender}:iData = {}) {}
```

But when i try to run this code, compiler gives me error "type, {} is missing following properties" ... where is the problem ?

edit: Full error : `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'iData': name, age 7  function doSomething({name, surname, age, gender}:iData = {})`

Comment: Posting the exact error message would help here, I suspect the interesting part of it is after "type, {} is missing following properties" ...
Also, you would likely have more help if you show what you try...

Comment: @TocToc here: "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'iData': name, age function doSomething({name, surname, age, gender}:iData = {}) {"

Comment: Isn't the error clear?

Comment: @TocToc Solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that empty object `{}` does not fulfill interface with mandatory fields like in your example - age and name. In other words `someData` type does not include empty object value. To have it working you need to or have all properties optional or set up default `name` and `age` inside default value like:

```
function parseData({name, surname, age, gender}:iData = {name: '', age: 0}) {
}
```

To be clear I don't think you should set here any default, as clearly setting age to some example value will pop up in some code part after as a bug. I would not set here any default and argument will be required, but still above should solve your problem.